# Error generating random numbers in Java. (code & error included)

Tags: java, android, random

I am receiving an error with this code that pops up Class file editor: **source not found inside the Random.class tab**. It was having issues with my line that says value =...

I am trying to create a general method the generate a random number between the two integers I pass in.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumGen {

    int value;
    Random rand;
    public RandomNumGen() {
        rand = new Random();
    }

    public int intRandom(int min, int max) {
        value = rand.nextInt(max) + min;
        return(value);
    }

    public int choiceRandom(int first, int second, int third, int fourth) {
        int random = intRandom(1, 400);
        if (random < 100) {
            return(first);
        }else if (random > 100 && random < 200) {
            return(third);
        }else if (random > 200 && random < 300) {
            return(fourth);
        }
        return(second);
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Format the code using 4 spaces before each code statement or by using `{}` available in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "source not found" error is because it tried to open the source to `java.util.Random` to help you debug and couldn't find it. The code looks right in that it should execute without errors; `Random.nextInt` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you pass it a non-positive number, but you're passing it 400. I don't get any errors running that code snippet and calling `choiceRandom(1, 2, 3, 4);`

However, logically the code is wrong -- `intRandom` doesn't return a number between `min` and `max`. You're calling `nextInt(max)`, which returns a number between `0` and `max-1`, and then adding `min`, making the range between `min` and `min+max-1`. You'd need to return `rand.nextInt(max-min) + min`

If you just want a method that takes a bunch of integers and returns one at random, a simpler implementation is:

```
public int choiceRandom(int... numbers) {
    return numbers[rand.nextInt(numbers.length)];
}
```

Comment: What exactly does int... do? Also I am still getting the same error, it is an IllegalArgumentException. Even when implementing your (awesome BTW) method I get the same error.

Comment: @Kirk It's a [varargs method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html); you pass it any number of ints and it stores them in an array named `numbers`. Are you sure the number you're passing to `rand.nextInt` is greater than 0?

Comment: somehow I was sending it a negative when I didn't think I was. I used Math.abs() on it and BAM it worked. Thank you very much for all your help. Also thanks for the TIPS!